# Custom Taxonomy Page redirect 404

Tags: taxonomy

I have a custom post type 'BLOG'. I created archive-blog.php file to display archives. Also I register a taxonomy with it named as 'blog-category' and created a page 'taxonomy-blog-category' while clicking on this taxonomy terms redirects me to the 404 page. Seems permalink problem. I have saved permalinks and rewrite_flush() but that also doesn't work.
Any help would be appreciated. Hope I'll get a positive response from your side. Thanx in advance.

Comment: What is url of your taxonomy terms?

Comment: First check is there any post and taxonomy that has been same named as your new taxonomy.

Comment: Hi thanks for helping me out the url of the term and taxonomy is this http://www.example.com/category/category-1 where category is the taxonomy and term is category-1

Comment: Yes, there is another taxonomy is registered with the same name. But they are registered with different CPT

Answer (score 0):

The taxonomy having rewrite rule with the name as 'category'. I changed it to different name and named it as 'blog-category', it will work for me in my case.